# How do I pass a stylesheet to a Local SVG Vector Image in React Native?

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg, react-native-stylesheet

I can determine the width and height inline

```
<WithLocalSvg width={50} height={50} asset={require("./assets/logo.svg")} />
```

But if I try to pass a width and height using a stylesheet then the width and height aren't inherited

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        paddingTop: 50,
    },
    tinyLogo: {
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
    },
    logo: {
        width: 66,
        height: 58,
    },
});
```

```
<WithLocalSvg style={styles.tinyLogo} asset={require("./assets/logo.svg")} />
```

I'm currently testing the iOS version

Comment: Width and height are attributes, not styles. You must specify them explicitly for the SVG element and can not put them in CSS

Comment: Is there a way to pass them to WithLocalSvg?

Comment: yes you can: width={50} height={50}

Comment: Of course, but I mean in a way that defines the variables outside of the inline, so that I don't have the const value littered everywhere.